# How to show categories instead of main navigation bar in magento iPhone theme

Tags: magento-community, magento-1.9

I'm using default magento iPhone theme for mobile viewers of my website, but defaultly iPhone theme show main navigation bar on the home page. But I need to show category list instead of main navigation bar. How should I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to edit you cms.xml file and remove reference of navigation block. Then Add a reference to a new block or phtml file. (here i have added a reference to page default_home_page which i created previously)

```
<cms_index_index translate="label">
    <label>CMS Home Page</label>
    <reference name="root">
        <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="homepage.banner" translate="label">
            <label>Home Page Banner(Mobile)</label>
            <action method="setElementClass"><value>front-banner</value></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/navigation" name="hp_nav" template="catalog/navigation/top.phtml" />
         **<block type="cms/block" name="homepage_block">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>homepage_block</block_id></action>
        </block>**
    </reference>
    <remove name="cms.wrapper"/>
</cms_index_index>
```